# ВКонтакте API для Android: вместо photo_big приходит camera_b.gif или null

Tags: vkontakte-api, android

В Android приложении я пытаюсь получить имя, город и большое фото пользователя этого приложения:

```
private final static String FIELDS = "photo,city,sex";
//private final static String FIELDS = "photo_big,city,sex";

private VKCallback<VKAccessToken> mCallback = new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
        VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, FIELDS));
        request.executeWithListener(mRequestListener);
    }
};

private VKRequest.VKRequestListener mRequestListener = new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        try {
            VKList<VKApiUserFull> list = (VKList<VKApiUserFull>) response.parsedModel;
            VKApiUserFull user = list.get(0);
            String sid = String.valueOf(user.id);
            String given = user.first_name;
            String family = user.last_name;
            String photo = user.photo_200;
            String place = (user.city != null ? user.city.title : "");
            boolean female = (user.sex == VKApiUserFull.Sex.FEMALE);
            // update UI
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    VKSdk.login(getActivity());
}
```

В отладчике вижу `response.responseString` (ВНИМАНИЕ свой `id` внизу я изменил):

```
{"response":[
{"id":59751333,
"first_name":"Alexander",
"last_name":"Farber",
"sex":2,
"city":{"id":1945522,"title":"Bochum"},
"photo":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e3\/n-yDMG4lvvk.jpg"
}]}
```

Но увы - не могу найти значение "photo" в своем объекте VKApiUserFull:

- `user.photo_100` содержит http://vk.com/images/camera_b.gif
- `user.photo_50`
  содержит http://vk.com/images/camera_c.gif
- `user.photo_200` вообще null

**Где же получить настоящий большой аватар пользователя**, то есть в моем примере https://pp.vk.me/c319319/v319319333/b7e3/n-yDMG4lvvk.jpg ?

Я пробовал поля `photo` и `photo_big`, искал и [на GitHub в VK SDK](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/tree/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/api/model)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, видимо ответ такой: **photo_50, photo_100, photo_200** можно получить через [VkApiUserFull](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/api/model/VKApiUserFull.java) объект.

Остальные (и более большие) фото VK-пользователя придется выуживать через `JSONObject`: **photo_400, photo_max, photo_max_orig** и (устаревший?) **photo_big**.

Вот пример моей информации (**id** изменен):

```
{"response":[{"id":59751333,
"first_name":"Alexander",
"last_name":"Farber",
"sex":2,
"city":{"id":1945522,"title":"Bochum"},
"photo":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e3\/n-yDMG4lvvk.jpg",
"photo_50":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e3\/n-yDMG4lvvk.jpg",
"photo_100":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e2\/Kt5-Wj2Ffv4.jpg",
"photo_200":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e1\/oJrjeeYO44I.jpg",
"photo_max":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e1\/oJrjeeYO44I.jpg",
"photo_big":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7df\/TnyKeffL_mU.jpg",
"photo_max_orig":"https:\/\/pp.vk.me\/c319319\/v319319333\/b7e0\/Zg6YbDQnqiM.jpg"
}]}
```

По этому поводу я создал [новое issue на GitHub](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/169).

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

VK SDK исправил эту ошибку в версии 1.6.2 и добавил там поля

```
public final static String FIELD_PHOTO_400_ORIGIN = "photo_400_orig";
public final static String FIELD_PHOTO_MAX = "photo_max";
public final static String FIELD_PHOTO_MAX_ORIGIN = "photo_max_orig";
public final static String FIELD_PHOTO_BIG = "photo_big";
```

Answer (score 2):

Именно этот юзер – забанен. Поэтому возвращается картинка-заглушка:

```
response: [{
  id: 59751333,
  first_name: 'Григорий',
  last_name: 'Емельяненко',
  deactivated: 'banned'
}]
```

Проверяйте наличие поля [`deactivated`](https://vk.com/dev/fields) в инфе юзера.

Comment: Нет, нет он не забанен - я просто не хочу публиковать свой `id`, так как он еще будет нужен в мобильном приложении для "секретного хеша"

Comment: Посмотрите [в той же документации](https://vk.com/dev/fields), что пишут про поля `photo_*`, в частности, `photo_400_orig` и `photo_max` – вероятно, именно эти поля вам нужны в этой задаче.